# How to get number of instances of a string in Json object using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I've below Json object that contain car associated to their manufacturer. From Json object, I want to get total number of cars as well as occurrence of a specific car in the object.

```
var Cars = { "manufacturer":"Car":
               [{"Saab":"Automobile AB"},
                {"Volvo":"V40"},
                {"BMW":"Estoril Blue"},
                {"Volvo":"V40"},
              ]};
```

I tried to use the `filter` but since filter is only specific for `Arrays` so cannot used it with Json object. Below is the source code.

```
var Cars = {"manufacturer":"Car":
               [{"Saab":"Automobile AB"},
                {"Volvo":"V40"},
                {"BMW":"Estoril Blue"},
                {"Volvo":"V40"},
               ]};

var volvo = "V40";

var numberOfCars = Cars.filter(function (x) {
       return x === volvo;
    }).length;
```

I expect the output of the above source code as 2. But I get an exception

> Cars.filter is not a function

I need you guys to please help me to get the occurrence of `V40` (that is 2), as well as total number of cars (which are 4).

Comment: 1) You can't have same key twice on same object, 2) filter is method on arrays not object

Comment: I just updated Json object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `filter` and then you can create object which has the duplicate car name as key and its number of occurences as val.

```js
const input = [{"Saab":"Automobile AB"}, {"Volvo":"V40"}, {"BMW":"Estorill Blue"}, {"Volvo":"V40"}];

const volvo = "V40";

const duplicateCars = input.filter(({Volvo}) => volvo == Volvo);

const duplicateCarName = Object.keys(duplicateCars[0])[0];

console.log({[duplicateCarName]:duplicateCars.length});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easy enough to walk over the properties of an object. One way is to use Object.entries to get an array of the properties and values;

```js
var Cars = [{"Saab":"Automobile AB"}, {"Volvo":"V40"}, {"BMW":"Estorill Blue"}, {"Volvo":"V40"}];

let properties = Object.entries(Cars);
console.log("Number of cars: ", Cars.length);
console.log("Number of Volvos: ", Cars.filter((car) => Object.keys(car)[0] === "Volvo").length);
```

Comment: Please add duplicate cars in Json object to get its more than one occurrences.

Comment: I've created the Cars array as above, I'm hoping this matches your data.. thanks!

Comment: Or is the cars array a property of the Cars object? The input is slightly confusing! :)